# Li tag equivalent in python?

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

So I have a Tkinter program, which is a nice IDE, since none of them aren't at my standards. Similar to most programs, they have the menu bar at the top? Since in HTML you use the `li` tag, What is the equivalent of the `li` tag in python?

Answer (score 0):

parse it as an int! Despite common belief, int parsage is always effective!

Comment: I wish I could -1 this. What would you parse as int? This is about the equivalent of the `li` tag in Tkinter.